# Is it possible to 'decorate' a function to change its internal variables and function calls?

Tags: javascript, reflection, decorator

I have this code

```
let someFunc1 = () => {
    const name1 = callFn({"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"})
    const name2 = callFn({"k1.1": "v1.1", "k2.1": "v2.1"})
    const name3 = callFn({"k1.2": "v1.2", "k2.2": "v2.2"})
}

let someFunc2 = () => {
    const name4 = callFn({"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"})
    const name5 = callFn({"k1.1": "v1.1", "k2.1": "v2.1"})
    const name6 = callFn({"k1.2": "v1.2", "k2.2": "v2.2"})
}
```

I'd like to add the following behaviour to all of these "someFunc" functions:

- Take a json object argument of the form { : {k1: v1}, : {k2: v2}, ... } which finds a variable (if it exists) with the same name as  and modifies the arguments to that callFn (if  exists then update it to , else create a new key-value pair)

Desired behaviour and outcome examples:

eg 1. If I wish to change the parameters to the callFn returning the variable "name2" by updating "k2.1" to "myNewValue" I would then be able to call
`someFunc1( { "name2": {"k2.1": "myNewValue"} } )`, which would effectively change `someFunc1` to read:

```
let someFunc1 = () => {
    const name1 = callFn({"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"})
    const name2 = callFn({"k1.1": "v1.1", "k2.1": "myNewValue"})
    const name3 = callFn({"k1.2": "v1.2", "k2.2": "v2.2"})
}
```

eg. 2  To add a new key-value pair ("myNewKey: "myNewValue") to the parameters passed to to the callFn returning the variable named "name6" I would be able to call
`someFunc2( { "name6": {"myNewKey": "myNewValue"} } )` which would effectively change `someFunc2` to read:

```
let somefunc2 = () => {
    const name4 = callfn({"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"})
    const name5 = callfn({"k1.1": "v1.1", "k2.1": "v2.1"})
    const name6 = callfn({"k1.2": "v1.2", "k2.2": "v2.2", "myNewKey": "myNewValue"})
}
```

I'm new to JS to not sure this is possible but if it is, guessing there might be some way to use decorators and/or reflection to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to add the missing properties into your parameter objects like this:

```js
const callfn = console.log

let somefunc2 = (args) => {
  const name4 = callfn({ "k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", ...args?.name4 })
  const name5 = callfn({ "k1.1": "v1.1", "k2.1": "v2.1", ...args?.name5 })
  const name6 = callfn({ "k1.2": "v1.2", "k2.2": "v2.2", ...args?.name6 })
}

somefunc2({ "name6": { "myNewKey": "myNewValue" } });
```

---

#### UPDATE: Munge the source and `eval`

Your recently added comment defines new restrictions where you cannot modify `somefunc2`.  Here's an evil way to escape that prison.

If your back is totally up against the wall and there's no other way out, then you may be able to do `const sourcecode = somefunc2.toString();` which returns **the source code** of the function.  Then use string operations to essentially *search and replace* or otherwise *munge* (programmatically edit) the source code for the implementation of `somefunc2`, and then create the new decorated function with `const decorated_somefunc2 = eval(modified_sourcecode)`  But this is an **atrociously evil** technique.

The code you write that modifies the source will likely be very fragile and finely tuned to accommodate the exact structure of the original source and all its idiosyncrasies.  This is a security vulnerability to say the least, but if you can vouch for the original code, and the internals of it are known (even if they cannot be modified) then in some cases it may work well enough.

Reminder, the whole point of this technique is to avoid directly modifying the source code for the original function.

```js
const callfn = console.log

let somefunc2 = () => {
  const name4 = callfn({ "k1": "v1", "k2": "v2" })
  const name5 = callfn({ "k1.1": "v1.1", "k2.1": "v2.1" })
  const name6 = callfn({ "k1.2": "v1.2", "k2.2": "v2.2" })
}

let source = somefunc2.toString();
let decoratedSource = decorateSource(source);
console.log(decoratedSource);
let decorated_somefunc2 = eval(decoratedSource); // pronounce `eval` as EVIL!

function decorateSource(source) {
  source = source.replace('()', '(args)');
  source = source.replace(
    /(const (name\d+) = callfn\((.*?) \}\))/g,
    'const $2 = callfn($3, ...args?.$2 })'
  );
  return source;
}

decorated_somefunc2({ "name6": { "myNewKey": "myNewValue" } });
```

**IMPORTANT**: Be sure to pronounce `eval` as *evil*! ;)

Comment: You can put the `...args?.namex` either before or after the other properties depending on which are intended to take precedence in the event that both are present.

Comment: Thanks @Wcyk this is a nice solution but I should have mentioned in the question that I wished to do this without modifying the existing functions. To be precise, the existing functions (eg. `someFunc1`) is legcacy code which I'm not permitted to change directy but l would like to achieve what you mention by adding a decorator (or some other way) to the function to effectively extend it with this bahaviour (and making it backward compatible since the arguments are optional) w/o changing the code inside the function

Comment: @amy I've added a _last resort_ technique, which I don't like (for reasons explained in my answer).  So, please handle with care!

Comment: thanks for that update, that does indeed achieve the desired effect so will mark as accepted answer, though not sure I will use it since, as you said, it's potentially quite a dangerous thing to do and am fearful of breaking legacy code in doing so. If I do employ it though, it's a shame JS doesn't yet support decoratorating functions with the `@` syntax as this simple one liner would make it a much more attractive option to other maintainers of the source code I'm sure

Comment: @amy I'm not sure what `@` syntax you're proposing.  Perhaps, in your question, you could have provided an example of the kind of syntax you were expecting.  I'm not sure it could be as simple as a "one-liner".